# Erro no findById de uma classe genérica para persistência e consultas usando Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Eu tenho uma classe genérica que estou usando para realizar consultas com o Hibernate JPA.

A minha classe está assim:

```
public class BaseRepositoryImpl<T> implements BaseRepository<T>
```

O problema é que em alguns métodos, como o `findById` logo abaixo, preciso explicitar o Tipo do objeto. E como é um tipo genérico, gera um erro.

```
@Override
public T findById(Long id) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    T t = em.find(Class<T>, id);   // ERRORRRR
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return null;
}
```

Como devo prosseguir para reparar esse erro?

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9202329

Comment: Ajudou um pouco. Mas, tive que implementar de outra forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na classe genérica, é preciso puxar manualmente o valor ao instanciar a a classe.

```
public BaseRepositoryImpl(Class<T> entity) {
    ...
    this.entity = entity;
}
```

Como é trabalhando com herança, as classes que vão fazer o reaproveitamento, ficaria implementado da seguinte forma:

```
public class PessoaRepositoryImpl extends BaseRepositoryImpl<Pessoa> implements PessoaRepository {

    public PessoaRepositoryImpl() {
        super(Pessoa.class);
    }

    ...

}
```

Dentro do construtor, é instanciado o super e podemos referênciar a classe explicitamente.